# Aegir login link not working

Tags: installation, aegir

I am trying to install [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org) on Ubuntu.

I followed the installation instructions

> ```
> sudo mysql_secure_installation
> echo "deb http://debian.aegirproject.org stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aegir-stable.list
> curl http://debian.aegirproject.org/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install aegir3
> ```

Everything got a `success`, but when I go to the login link that it provides me, the I get "server DNS address could not be found."

When I go to mydomain.com I get a 404 (which was working before).

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate providing a link answer, but in http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/install/#debianubuntu do steps 1-6 then you can install Aegir.

They main key being you need to do `sudo hostname yoursite.com` which was not mentioned in other docs.